# MATLAB: Does the execution of addpath/rmpath/savepath in one MATLAB instance affect other instances?

Tags: matlab, scientific-computing

Does the execution of addpath/rmpath/savepath in one MATLAB instance affect other instances?

**Motivation:** Imagine that you are developing a MATLAB package, which provides a group of functions to the users. You have multiple versions of this package being developed on a single laptop. You would like to test these different versions in multiple instances of MATLAB:

- You open one MATLAB window, type `run_test(DIRECTORY_OF_PACKAGE_VERSION1)`, and hit enter;
- While the first test is running, you open another MATLAB window, type `run_test(DIRECTORY_OF_PACKAGE_VERSION2)`, and hit enter.

See the pseudo-code below for a better idea about the tests.

No code or data is shared between different tests --- except for those embedded in MATLAB, as the tests are running on the same laptop, using the same installation of MATLAB. Below is a piece of pseudo-code for such a scenario.

```
% MATLAB instance 1

run_test(DIRECTORY_OF_PACKAGE_VERSION1);
```

```
% MATLAB instance 2

run_test(DIRECTORY_OF_PACKAGE_VERSION2);
```

```
% Code for the tests

function run_test(package_directory)

setup_package(package_dirctory);

RUN EXPERIMENTS TO TEST THE FUNCTIONS PROVIDED BY THE PACKAGE;

uninstall_package(package_directory);  

end
```

```
% This is the setup of the package that you are developing. 
% It should be called as a black box in the tests. 

function setup_package(package_dirctory)

addpath(PATH_TO_THE_FUNCTIONS_PROVIDED_BY_THE_PACKAGE);

% Make the package available in subsequent MATLAB sessions
savepath;  

end
```

```
% The function that uninstalls the package: remove the paths
% added by `setup_package` and delete the files etc.

function uninstall_package(package_directory)

rmpath(PATH_TO_THE_FUNCTIONS_PROVIDED_BY_THE_PACKAGE);

savepath; 

end
```

You want to make sure the following.

- The tests do not interfere with each other;
- Each test is calling funtions from the correct version of the package.

Hence here come our questions.

**Questions:**

1. Does the execuation of `addpath`, `rmpath`, and `savepath` in one MATLAB instance affect the other instance, **sooner or later?**
2. More generally, what kind of commands executed in one MATLAB instance can affect the other instance？

<s>3. What if I am running **only one instance of MATLAB, but invoke a `parfor` loop with two loops running in parallel?** Does the execution of addpath/rmpath/savepath in one loop affect the other loop, sooner or later? In general, what kind of commands executed in one parallel loop can affect the other loop?</s> (As pointed out by @Edric, this can be complicated; so let us not worry about it. Thank you, @Edric.)

Thank you very much for any comments and insights. **It would be much appreciated if you could direct me to relevant sections in the official documentation of MATLAB** --- I did some searching in the documentation, but have not found an answer to my question.

BTW, **in case you find that the test described in the pseudo code is conducted in a wrong/bad manner**, I will be very grateful if you could recommend a better way of doing it.

Comment: The `pathdef.m` file is shared, and modified using `savepath`. But I guess it's only read in while starting up, so a running MATLAB wouldn't be affected by changes to it. `addpath` and `rmpath` change stuff in memory, a different instance of MATLAB is a different process, and different processes don't share memory.

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo very much for the informative comments. So could we conclude that multiple tests running in multiple Matlab instances will not affect each other in terms of path? To be specific, consider the psedo code in my question. Many thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to install the package anew for each test. Why not install it, and then run all the tests? `savepath` is something that the user should run when they want to permanently alter their MATLAB path, I don't think it's good idea for software to use it behind the user's back.

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo. Test means to install the package from scratch, test it, and then uninstall it. By definition, a "test" should be identical to what will happen on the user's side. Otherwise, it is just a fake test. I suppose this kind of test is normal for people who develop real software packages.

Comment: Note that the pseudo-code in the question is just an over-simplified illustration. The installation/uninstallation of a real package can be much more sophisticated.

Comment: What I’m saying is that your software should not be installing and uninstalling itself. You should separate testing the package, and the installer for the package.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. From my point of view, installer and uninstaller are both reasonable parts of a decent software package. In a MATLAB package, they may be provided by a setup script and called by, for example, `setup` and `setup uninstall`. My test intends to verify not only the functions provided by the package but also the installer and uninstaller. It is not trivial to impement an (un)installer that works on all platforms and all recent versions of MATLAB, unless the package itself is trivial. Thus the (un)installer must be tested if the test is intended to be realistic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation page for the MATLAB Search Path [specifies at the bottom](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html#br8fy5q-1):

> When you change the search path, MATLAB uses it in the current session, but does not update pathdef.m. To use the modified search path in the current and future sessions, save the changes using savepath or the Save button in the Set Path dialog box. This updates pathdef.m.

So, standard MATLAB sessions are "isolated" in terms of their MATLAB Search Path *unless* you use `savepath`. After a call to `savepath`, new MATLAB sessions will read the updated `pathdef.m` on startup.

The situation with a parallel pool is slightly more complex. There are a couple of things that affect this. First is the parameter [`AutoAddClientPath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parpool.html#d123e63641) that you can specify for the `parpool` command. When `true`, an *attempt* is made to reflect the desktop MATLAB's `path` on the workers. (This might not work if the workers cannot access the same folders).

When a parallel pool is running, any changes to the `path` on the desktop MATLAB client are sent to the workers, so they can *attempt* to add or remove path entries. Parallel pool workers calling `addpath` or `rmpath` do so in isolation. (I'm afraid I can't find a documentation reference for this).

Comment: Thank you @Edric very much for the answer, and I appreciate particularly the reference to the documentation. Regarding "After a call to savepath, new MATLAB sessions will read the updated pathdef.m on startup", what about a MATLAB instance that is already running? If `pathdef.m` is read only upon startup, an instance already running would not be affected by the change in `pathdef.m` after its startup; am I undersantding it correctly? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes - `pathdef.m` is executed only on startup, so other sessions do not see the change (unless you explicitly call `pathdef` there).

Comment: So could we conclude that multiple tests running in multiple Matlab instances will not affect each other in terms of path? To be specific, consider the pseudo code in my question. Many thanks again!

Comment: That's definitely the case if none of the sessions calls `savepath`. If the sessions can call `savepath`, then sessions that start after the one making the call to `savepath` will see the updated path. Basically, `savepath` is not something that a well-behaved test should do, since it "drools" state on disk. Ideally, you'd use the "MATLAB Unit" test framework, which has specific support for path modifications via things like the PathFixture https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.fixtures.pathfixture-class.html

Comment: Thank you again @Edric for the clarification and reference, which are very informative. I hope, however, to mention that it is not the test that calls `savepath`, but the package being tested (as a black box) calls `savepath` --- I hope it is not considered something bad to do in a package. Many thanks.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of "package". I would consider something like calling `savepath` reasonable only during _installation_ of a package.

Comment: It is the installation (by the `setup_package` function in the pseudo code) and uninstallation of the package that call `savepath` . To test a package in a realistic way, we install it (`savepath` is called), try something, and then uninstall it (`rmpath` and `savepath` are called). Thank you.